# Switch to popup window with hotkey chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browser, browser-extension

I have created a chrome extension that has a popup.js, background.js, content.js files (amongst others).

When I do some kind of hot key on the main browser page, I want to refocus/switch to my popup window.

I have tried a number of things. I am not sure where to put this.

I am using Chrome manifest v2.

I have the following in my manifest.json:

```
  "commands": {
    "popupWindow" : {
      "suggested_key": {
           "default": "Ctrl+Shift+P" 
      },
      "description": "Switch to popup window"
  }
}
```

I have the following in my background.js:

```
  // Catch commands on the content page in the background script
  chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function (command) {
    if (command === "_execute_page_action") {
        console.log("execute_browser_action");
    } else if (command === "popupWindow") {
      console.log("popupWindow");
      } 
});
```

At the moment, it's just a log. I have tried getting the id of the popup window, but I can't seem to.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply use `_execute_page_action` instead of `popupWindow` in manifest.json and remove onCommand listener: everything will be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything in your `background.js` for this to work. Modify your `manifest.json` file to this:

```
{
  ...
  ...
  "commands": {
    "_execute_page_action" : {
      "suggested_key": {
           "default": "Ctrl+Shift+P",
           "mac": "MacCtrl+Shift+F"
      },
      "description": "Switch to popup window"
  }
  ...
}
```

You can get rid of the listener in `background.js`.